# Microsoft Word 2007: different spacing when certain style is preceding

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, typography

Is it possible to prevent Word form adding spacing between heading styles only?

For example, there is a **Heading 2** style, which has a "Before spacing" of 12px, which looks fine when it follows a paragraph of text. Is there I way I could prevent this spacing from being added when **Heading 2** is immediately following a **Heading 1** style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, my first thought would be to check if Word would not add spacing between two styles with the same base style when "Don't Add Spacing between Paragraphs of the Same Style" is enabled. However a quick test showed that wasn't the case.

I can only think of one other way which is a long shot but it might work depending on the structure of your document:

- If you translate the spacing before on your headings so instead you use spacing after on normal text then enable "Don't add spacing between paragraphs of the same style" it might result in what you are looking for.
- This way any normal text will have no spacing as usual, but a heading is used then spacing is added after the normal text (which looks like spacing before the heading).
- Furthermore since there is no spacing before on the headings they won't be spaced apart as what you originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question the answer is : No, there isn't.

But there is a very good workaround: Never use any automatic spacing between paragraphs, neither before nor after them! These automatic spacings are indeed a pretty dumb kind of automatism. They lead all the time to the kind of problem you brought us, that don't have solution while you keep using them. (By the way, Word has other dumb automatisms too, but lets stay with this one only.)

Want 100% control over spaces between paragraphs? Very easy: Just add 1 or more blank paragraphs when you want an extra line. Very simple and very quick, no? And this allows you set the exact amount of space you want on each place of you text. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create another.  Create style Subheading 1, based on Heading 2, so that it takes on its characteristics. Then modify it so it has no Before spacing.

This fails, however, if Heading 1 has an After spacing, which you want unless a Heading 2 is used.  The opposite is needed in that case. Create a Heading 1 NoAft style, with no After spacing; Heading 2 will already work. Unless you want none at all, then as above as well.